# Should we cast JQuery parameter in functions?

Tags: jquery

When you create a function involving jquery, it's easy to determine which local variables are jquery objects but when your function has a parameter, is it a good practice to re-cast the jquery object?

Ex:

```
Test($("#myId"));
function Test(target){
  $(target).css( "color", "red" );
}
```

I see a couple of advantages to handle parameter like this.  For example, you may pass DOM object or a selector string directly to the function without any casting.  On the pragmatic side, you're also going to get the jquery intellisense for your parameter.

However, I'm not sure if JQuery was made to be used that way...  re-casting jquery object seems to ignore some properties of the original object (like the prevObject).  Even if it's legit, it may also have an impact on the global performance.

Is it a good programming practice to re-cast jquery parameter in every function or should we assume that every programmer using your functions will follow the documentation?

Comment: no, it's the same as doing `$($(selector))`. Really is redundant. Once you create the jQuery object it won't change into something else just by passing it as reference. A common practice is to use `$` prefix for variables to show they are already jQuery objects .. like `$target`

Comment: Personally in some projects I do it because it is a safety net in cause someone does not pass in a jQuery object. Sort of nice since it is like an overload since you can pass in a selector and it would work. Downsides, little extra work if you already have the object, you could easily sniff if needed. It is all a personal opinion.

Comment: @charlietfl: It's obvious when you write it like this, but in large systems written in javascript, I've seen a lot of programmers getting confuse with the variable they're working with (i.e. dom vs jquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or should we assume that every programmer using your functions will follow the documentation?

No, you definitely should not. Assume that the programmer is stupid, has never read the documentation, and knows that it wants something to do with jQuery.

It can't *hurt* to cast it again. It can only help prevent novice mistakes.

> Even if it's legit, it may also have an impact on the global performance.

jQuery is fast enough that you shouldn't need to worry about this.